# Hovering over username to see Rep - Not being turned into ...k

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

When hovering over usernames in comments, the Reputation is shown as an exactly figure, it is not rounded to the nearest 1000.

For example this:

[image: This]

Should be this:

[image: Should be This]

---

**Edit - This is aparently by design, so I created a [Feature Request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321014/5620297) to get this changed**

Comment: Why do you think this is a bug? Why is this unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Well, if you look at this question, you will see that that your rep has been rounded (where it says *edit x mins ago by*).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Why should a tootlip be rounded, when the display on the page is?

Comment: What do you mean *When the display on the page isn't*? As far as I can tell, the *display on the page* is... The reason I thought is was a bug was because almost everywhere else, it is rounded. The only place it isn't is on the profile page (however that has a `,` separating the numbers, the tooltip doesn't)

Comment: Corrected, and you know what I meant... still? Why is that a bug?

Comment: @Oded I thought it was a bug because it is rounded everywhere it, so it should be rounded here..., was that a wrong assumption?

Comment: Why do you think it is rounded everywhere? That is - for what reason?

Comment: I thought it was rounded everywhere because it is easier to read. `324k` is easier to read than `324235`, like phone numbers (UK) are easier to read as `01234 567 890` than `01234567890`

Comment: That was the wrong assumption ;) - things are rounded because - there isn't enough space to show the whole number... The readability issue is a different thing though :)

Comment: @Oded Thanks a lot! Shall I post a feature request to add `,` to the rep in the tooptip (for readability)?

Comment: Sure - that's fine.

Comment: @Oded [Done.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321014/5620297) Thanks for the help!

Comment: This method of displaying "additional" information is pretty typical for a tooltip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep. With a tooltip we don't have as much of a spacing constraint as when showing things directly on the page.

Comment: Aren't you guys tired by now of making statements that are not Jon Skeet Safe™?