# Add , (comma) or round Reputation shown in tooltip

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation

After a discussion on this [Meta Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321003/5620297) (and finding out that it was not a bug, but by design), I have a feature request.

When hovering over a username in the comments, you can see their Reputation. However, it is very hard to read. Currently it is shown as `356892`. This is apparently designed this way due to there being no space restriction, however **just because you can** use the space, **doesn't necessarily mean you should**.

I propose for it to be shown as `324,235`, or `324k`, instead of `324235`. It will be rounded in the same way / using the same algorithm as the one used on questions and answers, where the user is displayed (so a smaller number like `17,123` would become `17.1k`).

Instead of:

[image: Currently Shown]

It should look like one of these:

[image: Have a , (comma)][image: Or rounded and have a k]

Comment: **Comment to test on! My Reputation has no `,` separating it, but my name ^^^ above this ^^^ does!**

Comment: Why a comma, and not a period?

Comment: @TZHX - same way we already use commas elsewhere?

Comment: @Oded No need to proliferate the disease.

Comment: @TZHX Note the difference between the period used as decimal point and and the comma used as thousands separator. The usage depends on the localization. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Examples_of_use) are some examples.

Comment: [Very similar (but slightly broader) feature-request on meta.SE.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240787/inconsistent-reputation-mouse-over-text)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Added commas to title in comments and on the user info hover.

With you in the next build.

Comment: It's to note that the next build is in fact online already. That was fast.

Comment: Any chance you could fix [these related issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240787/inconsistent-reputation-mouse-over-text) too? In particular, the tooltips in the weekly / monthly / quarterly / yearly rep rankings on the [users page](http://stackoverflow.com/users) are still missing commas.

Comment: Can you change the commas to dots in countries where they use the dot as decimal grouping character?

Comment: @Ferrybig - we don't do that in other places, and we don't have a way to do that.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - just pushed a fix, will be in the next build.